# ngIf scope defining value on itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 elements/scopes nested inside of each other:

```
dirElement(scope A)
   ngIfElement(scope B)
       isolateDirectiveElement(scope C)
```

Scope A has variable `test`. Scope C binds to it bidirectionally via an attribute, but at some point this binding ceases to work - if the scope A value is updated, even inside an $apply block or with $apply manually called, Scope C's value does not update. Inspecting the 3 scopes I noticed that at some point, scope B also has `test` defined on it. Given that, I believe the following is true:

1. With each $apply cycle, the two way binding attempts to update the parent value by *writing it directly onto the parent scope under `test`*.
2. With each $apply cycle, the two way binding attempts to update the child by making it read `test` from the parent scope. This can only ever read the value it just set and since nothing else sets that value on scope B, scope C is now stuck with the current value for `test`.

Essentially, the same reason you need a `.` in ngModel is applying to this scenario. That seems believable enough (I would still argue the behavior of (1) is needlessly dangerous), but somehow this situation has never causes bugs for me before (where an intermediate scope exists between an isolate scope and the scope it is pulling values from) and I'm fairly certain I've combined scopes in the same way before with no errors. A mild uniqueness of this situation is that scope A is also an isolate scope, but given that everything is a child scope of it/part of its template that shouldn't matter.

Am I correct that the best way to fix this is to change `test` to `test.value` (and define test as `{}` in scope A's controller)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want to hear, but the best solution is switching to the controllerAs way of working, and stop using $scope completely. You can read about this in the [style-guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide). 
The problem you have is not caused by the `.test` variable on the ngIf directive, but rather by the way transclusion works. In combination with the isolation you are using, it gets unpredictable.

> A mild uniqueness of this situation is that scope A is also an isolate scope, but given that everything is a child scope of it/part of its template that shouldn't matter.

O yes, this does matter! I don't recall the version, but this 'leakage' bug is fixed, and won't work anymore in the later AngualrJS versions. (and that's not even the whole problem)

You would really do yourself a favour, when you switch over to the (not so) new way of working with components, and controllerAs. Named controllers will fix this issue.
Converting your directives to components, and using a controller instead of a link function is actually not that difficult, and it saves you from all kinds of surprises like this.

Oh, and probably introducing the dot, will help, but given your setup with isolated $scopes, combined with transclusion, I would not be convinced it's a 100% cure in all cases.